# How to avoid naming of partitions with parted?

Tags: gpt, parted

If I run these commands:

```
parted -s /dev/sda \
    mklabel gpt \
    mkpart primary 1MiB 261MiB \
    set 1 esp on \
    mkpart primary 261MiB 50GiB \
    mkpart primary 50GiB 550GiB \
    mkpart primary 550GiB 100%

mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sda1
yes | mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2
yes | mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3
yes | mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda4
```

I get `primary` as name for all those partitions like this:

```
Model: ATA ST2000LM003 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB   273MB   fat32        primary  boot, esp
 2      274MB   53.7GB  53.4GB  ext4         primary
 3      53.7GB  591GB   537GB   ext4         primary
 4      591GB   2000GB  1410GB  ext4         primary
```

I don't want these names, how can I avoid such automatic naming?

---

**EDIT**

If I change the `mkpart` section like this:

```
parted -s /dev/sda \
    mklabel gpt \
    mkpart 1MiB 261MiB \
    set 1 esp on \
    mkpart 261MiB 50GiB \
    mkpart 50GiB 550GiB \
    mkpart 550GiB 100%
```

and run the script, I get these:

```
Error: Invalid number.
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.fat: unable to open /dev/sda1: No such file or directory
mke2fs 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
The file /dev/sda2 does not exist and no size was specified.
mke2fs 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
The file /dev/sda3 does not exist and no size was specified.
mke2fs 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
The file /dev/sda4 does not exist and no size was specified.
```

---

**EDIT**

`gparted` can do that:

[image]

Here I've removed the label from last partion with `gparted` BUT it doesn't show the command how it did that!

Comment: You can always change them later using the `name NUMBER name` switch.

Comment: @ajgringo619, I don't want any name. These names become the partition label on KDE's Dolphin and as a result I can't see the actual size of the partition under `Devices` category! On another machine I used `msdos` instead of `gpt` and with `msdos` I didn't have this issue.

Comment: I don't know if you can avoid them getting a name, but I guess "primary" comes from your own command (lines 3, 5, 7 and 7). I believe GPT doesn't have primary and extended  partitions, so these don't really mean anything else.

Comment: @Henrik, ok, I didn't know that! Let me check with this `mkpart 1MiB 261MiB \` style.

Comment: @Henrik, no, that doesn't work! With `cfdisk` I did `gpt` partitions several times without any name. I think, `cfdisk` actually doesn't have any option for name for `gpt` partitions.

Comment: You can find the solution here https://askubuntu.com/a/1069617/78090

Answer (score 2):

From [the parted docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#mkpart):

> **Command: mkpart *[part-type fs-type name] start end***
>   ...
>   *part-type* is one of ‘`primary`’, ‘`extended`’ or ‘`logical`’, and may be specified only with ‘`msdos`’ or ‘`dvh`’ partition tables. A
>   *name* must be specified for a ‘`gpt`’ partition table. Neither *part-type* nor *name* may be used with a ‘`sun`’ partition table.

You have to set a name for GPT partitions when using parted.

Comment: I'd `gpt` partitions on that disk, I made those with `cfdisk` and that didn't ask me for a `name`.

Comment: @EmonHaque then use cfdisk instead of parted.

Comment: `cfdisk` requires user interaction, I'm not sure whether I can use `cfdisk` in installation script like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541819/automating-arch-installation/541847#541847).

Comment: Well, unless you have some definite problem caused by the names, I don't see an issue. Put a random name, or keep using `primary` as the name, what difference does it make?

Comment: I can't see the partition size on the Dolphin file manager's device listings!

Comment: If that's you actual problem, then you should edit or ask a new question about that. When you do that, also add: How did you come to the conclusion that partition naming was the problem? What does Dolphin actually show? Have you checked if other GUI tools show the same problem?

Comment: I did install Arch with the name `primary` and Dolphin Instead of labeling them with the size of partitions labels all `primary`.

Comment: @EmonHaque, The label is not a list of the size, but some system tools will list a drive with the size, if there is no label. This is not a bug but a feature. There are other ways to see the size of a partition, and labels are useful for identification (of course a different label for each partition). Most file browsers have a way to show 'Properties' of a partition. I think you can find something like that also with Dolphin.

Comment: @sudodus, I actually wanted to remove those label with `gparted` and it did remove those `primary` labels and Dolphin showed the actual size. Since `gparted` can do that so should `parted` right? Let me know the command `gparted` used to remove those `primary` labels.

Comment: @EmonHaque you can find out from GParted itself. The logs usually include the command that GParted ran.

Comment: could you please help me with the location of the log file gparted puts out?

Comment: @EmonHaque I don't have a system with on hand, but it looks like this: https://gparted.org/screens/gparted_9_big.png

Comment: @muru, see the last **EDIT**, `gparted` doesn't show the command!

Comment: @EmonHaque then it's probably using the parted library directly. Another option you could try would be `gdisk`

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid naming the partition when using `parted` by providing an empty string.
I'll use the same quote from the [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#mkpart):

> **Command: mkpart *[part-type name fs-type] start end***
> ...
> *part-type* is one of ‘`primary`’, ‘`extended`’ or ‘`logical`’, and may be specified only with ‘`msdos`’ or ‘`dvh`’ partition tables. A
> *name* must be specified for a ‘`gpt`’ partition table. Neither *part-type* nor *name* may be used with a ‘`sun`’ partition table.

Now, let's dissect this (emphasize mine):

> *part-type* is one of ‘`primary`’, ‘`extended`’ or ‘`logical`’, and **may be specified only with** ‘`msdos`’ or ‘`dvh`’ partition tables.

So, when you create a `gpt` partition table **you don't use** `part-type` (for obvious reasons: there's only one type of partition). Which means that for `gpt` disks the command becomes

```
mkpart [name fs-type] start end
```

which means the first argument to `mkpart` is the `name`. Let's go back to the quote:

> A *name* **must be specified** for a ‘`gpt`’ partition table.

in other words that first argument is mandatory so whatever string follows the `mkpart` command it will be interpreted as the designated name for the partition. Now, how do you create a new partition without a name when using `parted` in interactive mode? You use an empty string `""` e.g.

```
(parted) mkpart "" 0% 100%
```

When you run that command in scripted mode you have to avoid those quotes to be expanded by the shell (to nothing), they need to be passed literally to `parted` so you have to escape/quote them,  e.g.

```
parted -a optimal -s /dev/sda mklabel gpt mkpart '""' 0% 100%
```

that is, in your particular case, instead of using *"primary"* which will used as a name for the partitions, you use an empty string:

```
parted -s /dev/sda \
    mklabel gpt \
    mkpart '""' 1MiB 261MiB \
    set 1 esp on \
    mkpart '""' 261MiB 50GiB \
    mkpart '""' 50GiB 550GiB \
    mkpart '""' 550GiB 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use `fdisk`

You can use `fdisk` from util-linux 2.31.1, probably also some other fairly new versions.

I tested with the following script file, where X should be replaced by the actual device letter for your target drive. Of course you have to set up the correct numbers of partitions and their sizes. You can find out what syntax to use by running `fdisk` interactively.

```
#!/bin/bash

LANG=C

echo "g
n


+256m

n


+1g

n




w" | fdisk /dev/sdX
```

### Explanation

The following list does not work (the comments are not accepted by fdisk), but it helps understanding the script above.

```
#!/bin/bash

LANG=C

echo "g     # gpt, GUID partition table
n           # new partition
            # default partition number
            # default start location
+256m       # size
            # default answer to partition name
n           # new partition
            # default partition number
            # default start location
+1g         # size
            # default answer to partition name
n           # new partition
            # default partition number
            # default start location
            # default end location at the drive's tail end
            # default answer to partition name
w           # write to the drive" | fdisk /dev/sdX
```

### Verification that there will be no 'Name'

```
$ sudo partprobe;sleep 1;LANG=C sudo parted /dev/sdc p
Model: Kingston DataTraveler G3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 4010MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  269MB   268MB
 2      269MB   1343MB  1074MB
 3      1343MB  4010MB  2667MB
```

Comment: What about the last partition? I want `/dev/sda4` to take rest of the available space.

Comment: @EmonHaque, It is simple, use the default (an empty line) and it will use the rest of the available space.